# Where should questions regarding building complicated operations in spreadsheet software be asked?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Where should questions regarding building complicated operations in spreadsheet software be asked?

In my particular case I have a random amount of measurements done of a certain quantity done each day and put into a column along with the date and hour of the measurement and I would like to get an average for each day automatically.

I don't see a dedicated spreadsheet site, but maybe I am blind? Otherwise the problem is so close to programming that maybe the Stack Overflow would be the place?

Comment: _"regarding building complicated operations in spreadsheet software"_ Isn't that programming related? If so you should ask at Stack Overflow.

Comment: You have to be careful. Some on Stack Overflow consider putting a formula into a spreadsheet cell not a programming task. Those prefer these questions go on Super User. Having a spreadsheet with hundreds of formulas and loops and what not, it is hard to deny it comes remarkably close to programming

Comment: @rene _"Some on Stack Overflow consider putting a formula into a spreadsheet cell not a programming task."_ Well, it's more or less like programming macros, no?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261875/are-excel-formulas-on-topic

Comment: @rene Also SO supports tags like [excel] amd such (unfortunately I can't try what exactly ATM :-P). If it's just a plain formula, maybe asking at [math.se] might be more appropriate.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I'm not saying don't or do, I'm only trying to convey some warnings up front to prevent disappointment later ...

Comment: _@Empischon_ _"I don't see a dedicated spreadsheet site"_ I don't see one either  AFAIK. If it's a complex macro placed in the spreadsheet it might be appropriate for SO, if it's really a math formula to create in 1st place [math.se] might be more appropriate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Excel or OpenOffice sheets questions would work on [Super User](https://superuser.com). If you're using Google Sheets, [Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com) would work.

That said, *chances* are that a question that's pretty much "I need to do this, this and this, how do I write it?" wouldn't go that well. Show what you've tried, and where you run into trouble, and you'll do a lot better.

Comment: Questions about spreadsheet formulas are also on-topic in [so]. Ref. [Are spreadsheet formulas on topic?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261875/1595451). Disclaimer: I'm a google-sheets gold tag badge holder in Web Applications and Stack Overflow. P.S. The reference was [mentioned](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/331643/where-should-questions-regarding-building-complicated-operations-in-spreadsheet#comment1081778_331643) in comments by rene previously, but they previously warned that might not be well received. Besides me, there are other google-sheets gold tag badge holders.